# Cannot read property 'tagName' of null error in react testing library with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testcase

I am writing test cases using react testing library with jest. i want to check dropdown list of another Multiselect to be present when i select from first dropdown.

import user from '@testing-library/user-event'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null

```
  101 |     const { getByText, container } = render(<Product />)
  102 |     const actionDiv = container.querySelector('#option-0')
> 103 |     user.click(actionDiv)
      |          ^
  104 |     await act(async () => {
  105 |       await waitFor(() => expect(getByText(/10.or/i)).toBeInTheDocument())
  106 |     })
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid to use `container` to query elements like it said [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#container-1).

Use queries like you did in your `expect` function.
You have alot of those to help you [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/).